# Vue routing – '/' root url still active

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a simple routing:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Start',
      component: Start
    },
    {
        path: '/plan',
        name: 'Plan',
        component: Plan
    },
    {
        path: '/cel',
        name: 'Cel',
        component: Cel
    }
  ]
})
```

And I have also a simple menu:

```
<ul class="nav nav--top">
     <li><router-link to="/">Start</router-link></li>
     <li><router-link to="/plan">Plan</router-link></li>
     <li><router-link to="/cel">Cel</router-link></li>
</ul>
```

It works fine, but I have a problem with active link class. A start url '/' has always class 'router-link-active' even I have active other url.

```
<ul class="nav nav--top">
    <li><a href="#/" class="router-link-active">Start</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#/plan" class="">Plan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/cel" class="router-link-active">Cel</a></li>
</ul>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I think you need to use `exact` prop, something like `<router-link to="/plan" exact>Plan</router-link>` --- https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html

Comment: Thanks. I added `exact` to `/` url and it works now.
```<li><router-link to="/" exact>Start</router-link></li>```